# VBA Run time Error '70': Could not Set the list property. Permission Denied

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update the data by clicking the Listbox,but getting error, please see my code below.

> Using below code to display the list box value to text boxes

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
i = Me.ListBox1.ListIndex
Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True
Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.ListBox1.Column(0, i)
Me.TextBox2.Value = Me.ListBox1.Column(1, i)
Me.TextBox3.Value = Me.ListBox1.Column(2, i)
Me.TextBox4.Value = Me.ListBox1.Column(3, i)
End Sub
```

> Trying to update data with following code and getting error.

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()
If ListBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
With ListBox1
.List(.ListIndex, 0) = TextBox1.Value
.List(.ListIndex, 1) = TextBox2.Value
.List(.ListIndex, 2) = TextBox3.Value
.List(.ListIndex, 3) = TextBox4.Value
End With
End If
End Sub

enter code here
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike ComboBoxes, you can't edit values in a ListBox on the fly like this. You have to delete the entry and insert one back in, with your new values. I'm not sure this is the most elegant way to do it, but the following works:

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()
    Dim values(3)
    Dim u As Long
    u = ListBox1.ListIndex
    If u <> -1 Then
            values(0) = TextBox1.Value
            values(1) = TextBox2.Value
            values(2) = TextBox3.Value
            values(3) = TextBox4.Value

         With ListBox1
         .RemoveItem u
         .AddItem values(0), u
            .List(u, 1) = values(1)
            .List(u, 2) = values(2)
            .List(u, 3) = values(3)
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    With Me
        i = .ListBox1.ListIndex
        .ListBox1.Selected(i) = True
        .TextBox1.Value = .ListBox1.Column(0, i)
        .TextBox2.Value = .ListBox1.Column(1, i)
        .TextBox3.Value = .ListBox1.Column(2, i)
        .TextBox4.Value = .ListBox1.Column(3, i)
    End With
End Sub
```

As I say, not elegant: I had to store the `values` of `TextBox1` etc. in the array as when the `RemoveItem` runs, the Index changes which causes the `ListBox1_Click` to run - resetting all the Textboxes.

Comment: That's odd, it works on my machine. If you debug, what **value** is U set to?

Comment: its just say Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)' Unspecified error

Comment: the value is 42827

Comment: Well, 42,827 is larger than the `Integer` type allows. I've changed my answer (now I know you're dealing with that many rows) to reflect this, altering the `Integer` to `Long` for both `u` and `i`.

Comment: still a same error, 42827 showing in my textbox1 actualy a date 04/02/2017, does it matter?

Comment: `u` should be the `ListIndex` value - i.e. the row number, not the value being put into the cell. In the immediate window, type `debug.print u` to see the value of `u`.

Comment: debug.Print u 
 1

Comment: Is your list based on a range on a sheet somewhere (using `RowSource` maybe)?

Comment: Yes, Row Source Properties for Text Box set to DataEntry!A2:D5000

Comment: Then I'd probably code it to change the value in the cells, not the value in the ListBox

Comment: Thanks for hanging out with me CLR22, I got it.