# Update userform from another userform, error "Could not set the column property"

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA,

I have an excel worksheet, which is updating userform using another userform

I'll call the userform needed to be updated as "userform1"
Userform used as updating form as "userform2"

Here is the code to update the userform needed to be updated

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    UserForm2.TextBox1.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(1)
    UserForm2.TextBox2.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(2)
    UserForm2.TextBox3.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(3)
    UserForm2.TextBox4.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(4)
    UserForm2.TextBox5.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(5)
    UserForm2.TextBox6.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(6)
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

Here is the code that userform used for updating "userform1"

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(1) = time
        UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(2) = Me.TextBox1.Text
        UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(3) = Me.TextBox2.Text
        UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(4) = Me.TextBox3.Text
        UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(5) = Me.TextBox4.Text
        UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(6) = Me.TextBox5.Text
        UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(7) = Me.TextBox6.Text
        Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
        Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
        Me.TextBox3.Value = ""
        Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
        Me.TextBox5.Value = ""
        Me.TextBox6.Value = ""
End Sub
```

When I fill the userform2 to update userform1, I have this error

```
Run-time error '70':

Could not set the column property. Permission denied.
```

Can someone please advise where did I'm doing wrong?
Any help very appreciated.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348934/vba-run-time-error-70-could-not-set-the-list-property-permission-denied

Comment: @user2648008: Sorry. Just saw your link. I was testing what I wrote...

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the relevant row and column of the listbox to write to it. Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rw As Long

    '~~> Get the row which was selected
    rw = UserForm1.ListBox1.ListIndex
    If rw = - 1 The Exit Sub

    With UserForm1.ListBox1
        .List(rw, 1) = Time
        .List(rw, 2) = TextBox1.Text
        .List(rw, 3) = TextBox2.Text
        .List(rw, 4) = TextBox3.Text
        .List(rw, 5) = TextBox4.Text
        .List(rw, 6) = TextBox5.Text
        .List(rw, 7) = TextBox6.Text
    End With

    TextBox1.Value = "": TextBox2.Value = "": TextBox3.Value = ""
    TextBox4.Value = "": TextBox5.Value = "": TextBox6.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply, thank you for the advise, I've tried it but there is an error

"Method or data member not found"

Comment: on
With UserForm1.ListBox1
        .List(rw, 1) = Time
        .List(rw, 2) = TextBox1.Text
        .List(rw, 3) = TextBox2.Text

Answer (score 0):

I've tried myself, and for now I'll try to get on sheet first rather focus on userform2, I need to find out how to insert table row without following formatting above it

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim Kolom As Long
Dim Lembar As Worksheet
Set Lembar = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Kolom = Lembar.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Dim time As Date
time = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm")



If Range("a2") <> "" Then

'Lembar.Range("a2").Select
Range("a2").EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

End If

If Range("a2") = "" Then

Lembar.Range("A2").Value = time
Lembar.Range("B2").Value = Me.TextBox1
Lembar.Range("C2").Value = Me.TextBox2
Lembar.Range("D2").Value = Me.TextBox3
Lembar.Range("E2").Value = Me.TextBox4
Lembar.Range("F2").Value = Me.TextBox5
Lembar.Range("G2").Value = Me.TextBox6

End If
```

It succeed on inserting new row and the value but it's following format above it. I don't want that thing to happen, after that we can take my primary question for next step.